# Match two vectors and replace in string

Tags: r, replace, match

The following problem: I have two data frames where I want to match one vector from data frame data1 with a vector from data frame data2.

```
data1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("horse", "duck", "bird"), v2 = c(1,2,3))
data2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("car, horse, mouse", "duck, bird", "bird"))
```

If a character string in data2 is matched it should be replaced by the corresponding value v2 from data1. The result looks like as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data1)) data2[,1] <- gsub(data1[i,1], data1[i,2], data2[,1], fixed=T)
data2
```

However, is there an idea using a vectorized solution instead of a for loop to create a better performance with huge datasets?

Thanks in advance!

--Updated:

What happens when I have the case, that both dataframes don´t have the same length?

`data2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("car, horse, mouse", "duck, bird","bird", "bird"))`

When I use this solution:

```
data2$v1 <- mapply(sub, data1$v1, data1$v2, data2$v1)
```

Then I get the following warning message:

> 1: In mapply(sub, data1$v1, data1$v2, data2$v1) :   longer argument
>   not a multiple of length of shorter 2: In mapply(sub, data1$v1,
>   data1$v2, data2$v1) :   longer argument not a multiple of length of
>   shorter

However, the mgsub solution works perfect! Thank you!

Comment: What do you *want* to have happen when the `data.frame`s aren't the same length?

Comment: I`d like to match specific strings in other dataframes. The first dataframe works as a word library with indexing numbers.

Comment: That doesn't match the process you describe with your `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the updated `data2`.  The `nrows` between `data1` and `data2` are different, Here, we are assuming that any match between `v1` columns of both datasets should be replaced by the corresponding value of `v2` column in `data1`.

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(as.character(data1$v1), data1$v2, data2$v1)
#[1] "car, 1, mouse" "2, 3"          "3"             "3"
```

**Note** `mgsub` has some error handling that deals with situations where a substring is found within a larger string and both are in the '*to be replaced*' list.  Here's an example with `horse` and `horses`:

```
data1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("horse", "duck", "bird", "horse", "horses"), v2 = 1:5)
data2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("car, horses, mouse", "duck, bird, horse", "bird"))

library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(data2$v1, data1$v1, data1$v2)

## [1] "car, 1s, mouse"    "2, bird, horse"    "3"                 "car, 4s, mouse"    "duck, bird, horse"
## Warning message:
## In stri_replace_all_fixed(data2$v1, data1$v1, data1$v2) :
##   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

library(qdap)
mgsub(as.character(data1$v1), data1$v2, data2$v1)

## [1] "car, 5, mouse" "2, 3, 4"       "3"
```

`mgsub` makes sure the longer words are replaced first.  This makes `mgsub` slower but safer.  Depending on your data type/needs either solution here may be of use.

Comment: I'm guessing that this might be more like what they are looking for. +1

Answer (score 5):

Most of the arguments in the "stringi" package accept vectorized inputs, so you should be able to use `stri_replace_all`, like this:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(data2$v1, data1$v1, data1$v2)
# [1] "car, 1, mouse" "2, bird"       "3"
```

To get your `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(v1 = stri_replace_all_fixed(data2$v1, data1$v1, data1$v2))
#              v1
# 1 car, 1, mouse
# 2       2, bird
# 3             3
```